# Need to rebuild array from EBS volumes on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, software-raid, amazon-ebs

I shutdown a bunch of instances on our AWS account as we're no longer developing for a product. After shutting down everything, before hitting the delete button on the EBS volumes, we decided we would like to take dumps of our databases just for the heck of it. The problem is, I had a replica set of Mongo databases and I don't remember which of the 12 EBS volumes, (there was 4 EBS volumes per db in a RAID10 configuration) were grouped together. I'd need to be able to rebuild the array from the original EBS volumes, get the database backup, and get a raw dump using mongodump and use that as our backup point.

What's the best way to handle a situation like this?

Comment: Write documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As you've not terminated your instances, just turn your EC2 instances back on. You should have a record of the attached instances on the stopped instances. (as long as you weren't using ephemeral storage and never took snapshots)